# Extra Characters while using XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called Map_Data and the data looks like:

```
 ID    SoCol                                                              Descol  
 125   case Per_rating when 5 then 'Good' when 4 then 'Ok' else null end  D_Code
```

And I wrote a query on this particular row and the query is:

```
SELECT  Params = ( SELECT   DesCol + ' = ''' + SoCol + ''''
                   FROM     dbo.Map_Data  t1
                   WHERE   ID = 125
                   FOR
                   XML PATH('')
                 )
```

and I get the output as :

```
D_Code = 'case per_rating&#x0D; when 5 then 'Good'&#x0D; when 4&#x0D; then 'Ok'&#x0D; end'
```

Can anyone tell me why i am getting `'&#x0D;'` it and how can i correct it?

Comment: Check the content of Mapdata , me thinks there are #13 (Carriage Returns) in it. They might not be visible in whatever you are using to display the table content. Given where they are it looks SoCol was prettified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This slight change will make the ugly entities go away, but they won't eliminate carriage returns (look at the results in Results to Text, not Results to Grid, to see them):

```
SELECT  Params = ( SELECT   DesCol + ' = ''' + SoCol + ''''
                   FROM     dbo.Map_Data  t1
                   WHERE   ID = 125
                   FOR
                   XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)');
```

If you want to get rid of the CR/LF too you can say:

```
SELECT  Params = ( SELECT   REPLACE(REPLACE(DesCol + ' = ''' + SoCol + '''', 
     CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
                   FROM     dbo.Map_Data  t1
                   WHERE   ID = 125
                   FOR
                   XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)');
```

Also I'm not sure how you're going to use the output but if you're going to evaluate it later with dynamic SQL you're going to need to replace the embedded single quotes (`'`) with two single quotes (`''`). Otherwise it will blow up because they're also string delimiters.

Comment: Please note that using `.value` is much slower than using without. I had a UDF full of such calls and it caused quite a bit of performance hit.

Comment: @Sebazz Great. Can you show how to get the same output without using `.value`?

Comment: You cannot. That is the disadvantage. If possible, you can filter the value in application code. That can work quite well in many cases, but some queries on your Params column may not work well because escaped XML will be in the middle.

Comment: @Sebazz Ok so if users want the database to returned the required output then they can't use your approach. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by just keeping all the code in the single quote in one line. I too had similar issue and it is resolved by keeping all the code in one line.